# iOS occassionally gets a "smeared look"

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css

Occasionally while a page is loading, it appears as though there is some sort of rendering error, where the page just smears the font that it is currently rendering.

I cannot actively reproduce this with code, and it happens all throughout the site.

I'd like to provide you with code or a URL to reproduce this, however, due to my NDA with this client I cannot.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Rendering Smears]

Has anyone seen this and would you happen to know what might be causing it?

Comment: Is that a screenshot from an actual device or a simulator? Does the effect "scroll" with the page?

Comment: This is a screenshot from an actual device, and yes it stays. It goes away if I interact with the page, for instance, open a modal.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  I had something similar on an Android device recently but just attributed it to a momentary glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tooling around for awhile, I discovered that the problem lied with too many "scrollTo"s on the site. Causing this type of blurring.

Weird? Yes.